# Make calls to Java code from the native code?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I know that its possible to call functions in the native code from the java code, but what about vice-versa?

Is it possible for me to call a Java function from the native C code?

Comment: Yes it is possible, here is a pretty good article explaining how to do this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI. Also there are _a lot_ of posts about this on SO, search for some of them to see if their answers help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You are interested in the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Comment: I've figured it out since then, thanks for answering though :)